# why transform style in css placed my text outside of its parent div?

Tags: html, css, svg

i have an svg , and i want to have some text inside of it , with a text tag i cant do it . because working with text tag in svg is not a good idea for me (no-wrapping lines ,breaking lines and height of text element ,cant deal with it) .
so i got foreignObject tag and define a div inide it with h2 tag and p tag like so

```css
 
 
 
 .st3{fill:url(#XMLID_2_);}
 .st4{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.7985;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.7985;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:4.6022,4.6022;}
 .st6{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.8067;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st7{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.8067;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:4.5551,4.5551;}
 
 
  
  #campain {
    x: 20;
    y: 72;
    perspective: 64px;
    perspective-origin: 43%;
}

#campain > .desc {
    font-size: 8px;
    direction: rtl;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(8.5deg) rotateZ(1deg) rotateX(0.6deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="catalogueSvg" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 800 600">
<linearGradient id="XMLID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-23.964" y1="247.5691" x2="222.1289" y2="233.4258">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
    <stop offset="0.9999" style="stop-color:#CDCDCD" />
   </linearGradient>

<polyline id="XMLID_8_" class="strk st3" points="31.3,36.5 31.3,452.3 157.8,413.1 157.8,94.2 31.3,36.5 " />
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="strk st4" x1="156.3" y1="407.3" x2="154.1" y2="408" />
     <line class="strk st5" x1="149.7" y1="409.3" x2="37.1" y2="442.5" />
     <line class="strk st4" x1="34.9" y1="443.1" x2="32.7" y2="443.8" />
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="strk st6" x1="30.1" y1="45.9" x2="32.2" y2="46.8" />
     <line class="strk st7" x1="36.4" y1="48.6" x2="151.2" y2="98.8" />
     <line class="strk st6" x1="153.2" y1="99.7" x2="155.4" y2="100.7" />
    </g>
   </g>


 <foreignObject id="campain" width="150" height="384" >
   
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <div class="desc">
        <h2>bla bla ba</h2>
        <p>bla bla ba bla bla ba bla bla ba 
          bla bla ba bla bla ba bla bla ba
          ......
        </p>
   </div>
    </body>
   
  </foreignobject>
  </svg>
```

the text behave what i want till have no transform style , i mean its contain in its parent element and inherit width , height , behave true on responsive staffs , but when i assume transform style in css to render perspective behaves its jump out of parent and stand left of window . wtf ?!
any idea ?

Comment: any idea ?! whats the best way to have text in a svg code ?!

Answer (score 0):

The changes I made: In HTML I've added a div `#foWrap` and I'm using it in the CSS instead of your `#campain`. Also you have x and y in the css. I've moved x and y for the #campain in the SVG. Also I'm using different angles for the transform, since yours are very small.

I hope this is what you were asking.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
 
 
 .st3{fill:url(#XMLID_2_);}
 .st4{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.7985;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.7985;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:4.6022,4.6022;}
 .st6{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.8067;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st7{fill:none;stroke:#BBBDBF;stroke-width:0.8067;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:4.5551,4.5551;}
 
 
  
  #foWrap {
    perspective: 640px;
    perspective-origin: 43%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

 #foWrap .desc {
    font-size: 8px;
    direction: rtl;
    
    transform: rotateY(-50deg) rotateZ(10deg) rotateX(60deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg id="catalogueSvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 300 600">
<linearGradient id="XMLID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-23.964" y1="247.5691" x2="222.1289" y2="233.4258">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
    <stop offset="0.9999" style="stop-color:#CDCDCD" />
   </linearGradient>

<polyline id="XMLID_8_" class="strk st3" points="31.3,36.5 31.3,452.3 157.8,413.1 157.8,94.2 31.3,36.5 " />
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="strk st4" x1="156.3" y1="407.3" x2="154.1" y2="408" />
     <line class="strk st5" x1="149.7" y1="409.3" x2="37.1" y2="442.5" />
     <line class="strk st4" x1="34.9" y1="443.1" x2="32.7" y2="443.8" />
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <line class="strk st6" x1="30.1" y1="45.9" x2="32.2" y2="46.8" />
     <line class="strk st7" x1="36.4" y1="48.6" x2="151.2" y2="98.8" />
     <line class="strk st6" x1="153.2" y1="99.7" x2="155.4" y2="100.7" />
    </g>
   </g>


 <foreignObject id="campain" width="250" height="384" x="80" y="50" >
   
 <div id="foWrap"> 
   <div class="desc">
        <h2>bla bla ba</h2>
        <p>bla bla ba bla bla ba bla bla ba 
          bla bla ba bla bla ba bla bla ba
          ......
        </p>
   </div>
 </div>
   
 </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: cool , but its not the matter . the text do not follow its container elements behave on resizing window . when you resize and inspect the element . the text div container follow the svg behave and great deal . but the text just stand there like a **** ;)

Comment: Apparently it's the 3d transform that won't work properly.

Comment: any idea to do some thing like that ? :)

Comment: Maybe if you can explain what you are aiming for ... I mean the final result. There may be an other way of doing it.

Comment: dear @enxaneta i want the text to be sitting on the perspective plane svg (as if it is printed on the svg page) and also responsive view ;)